# powershell code to checkout, replace a string and checkin

Tags: powershell, tfs

Is there any sample code in powershell to Checkout a file, replace a string and check in the file back with comments. I am trying to achieve this in TFS.

Comment: are you talking about version control like mercurial or git?

Comment: @SteveRathbone he/she tagged TFS.. so I guess VSS?

Comment: @sonjz ah my bad, i completely missed that tag :/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - This is with reference to TFS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using script like this:

```
$filePath = 'c:\tfs\foo\bar.csproj'
tf edit $filePath
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) throw "tf edit failed"
(Get-Content $filePath) -replace 'v4\.0', 'v4.5.1' | Out-File $filePath -Enc Utf8
tf checkin $filePath /noprompt --% /comment:"My checkin comment"
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) throw "tf checkin failed"
```

Note that you need to add the path of tf.exe to the $env:path variable or use the fully qualified path to tf.exe e.g.:

```
$tf = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe'
& $tf edit $filePath
```